# How to stop audio when another app plays audio in flutter

Tags: flutter, audio-player

I have a problem achieving my goal using audio_session plugin, I want to stop audio when another app plays audio. Just when another audio/video player app starts playing or when a phone call is made.

I am using audio_players package, I also tried just_audio.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check flutter audio_session. This plugin informs the operating system of the nature of your audio app (e.g. game, media player, assistant, etc.) and how your app will handle and initiate audio interruptions (e.g. phone call interruptions). It also provides access to all of the capabilities of AVAudioSession on iOS and AudioManager on Android, providing for discoverability and configuration of audio hardware.

```
AudioSession.instance.then((audioSession) async {
    audioSession.interruptionEventStream.listen((event) {
      if (event.begin) {
        switch (event.type) {
          case AudioInterruptionType.duck:
            // Here you could lower the volume
            break;
          case AudioInterruptionType.pause:
          case AudioInterruptionType.unknown:
            // Here you should pause your audio
            player.pause();
            // AND ALSO broadcast the new state
            playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(playing: false));
            break;
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Example :

```
  Future<void> _init() async {
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    // Handle audio interruptions.
    session.interruptionEventStream.listen((event) {
      if (event.begin) {
        if (_playing) {
          pause();
          _interrupted = true;
        }
      } else {
        switch (event.type) {
          case AudioInterruptionType.pause:
          case AudioInterruptionType.duck:
            if (!_playing && _interrupted) {
              play();
            }
            break;
          case AudioInterruptionType.unknown:
            break;
        }
        _interrupted = false;
      }
    });
    // Handle unplugged headphones.
    session.becomingNoisyEventStream.listen((_) {
      if (_playing) pause();
    });
```

a full example is provided at:

https://pub.dev/packages/audio_session/example

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried it event tried the example in the repo but still not getting any interrupts

Comment: @AhmedRagab then try old school way and call native code using NotificationCenter for ios and LocalBroadcastManager for android you can check this library : https://github.com/florent37/Flutter-AssetsAudioPlayer/blob/master/darwin/Classes/Music.swift

Comment: I think I need only a way to make the audioSession work as needed.
I need for android only

Comment: @AhmedRagab Try to review your code perhaps you miss something... i leave u some example 4 help...

Comment: I have the plugin example iteself and I got no event when another app starts playing sound